# Error when initializing Zurb Magellan 6

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, magellan

Having trouble understanding the docs on how to initialize a Magellan menu (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html)

**Error:**

`Uncaught TypeError: this.$element.data is not a function
Magellan @ foundation.js:4192
(anonymous function) @ test2.php:174`

**Code**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/foundation.css'/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <div class="sections">
                <section id="first" data-magellan-target="first">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-12 columns">
                            <p>
                                lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
                                <br><br><br>
                                ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
                                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id="second" data-magellan-target="second">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-12 columns">
                            <p>
                                lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
                                <br><br><br>
                                ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
                                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id="third" data-magellan-target="third">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-12 columns">
                            <p>
                                lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
                                <br><br><br>
                                ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
                                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <ul id="nav" class="vertical menu" data-magellan>
                <li><a href="#first">First Arrival</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second">Second Arrival</a></li>
                <li><a href="#third">Third Arrival</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
    var target = document.getElementById('nav');
    var elem = new Foundation.Magellan(target);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/e80Luthg/). Is it doing what you're after?

Comment: @Yass I don't think so unfortunately. I'm trying to replicate the right-side menu on the link provided in OP, which updates as a user scrolls down.

Comment: The bit that says Setup, Sticky Navigation, Javascript reference?

Comment: I played around with this yesterday and I was able to get rid of the error by using the latest jquery version: [JQuery v2.2.0](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js)